# send some props to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, togglebutton

for details: I have a context file that export a theme and a function (theme value and toggleThemeMode function) and in Header.jsx component I wanna use these to change the background by Toggle.jsx component.
I don't know exactly how send some props to Toggle.jsx component to change these values ...

////////////////////////////////// theme.jsx (context) //////////////////////////////////

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const DARK = "DARK";

const ThemeContext = createContext();

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState({ mode: "LIGHT" });

  const toggleThemeMode = () => {
    setTheme(theme.mode === DARK ? "LIGHT" : DARK);
  };

  

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleThemeMode }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);

export { ThemeProvider, useTheme, DARK };
```

////////////////////////////////// Header.jsx //////////////////////////////////

```
import React from "react";
import { DARK, useTheme } from "../../contexts/theme";
import { Toggle } from "./toggle";

import logo from "../../assets/images/logo.svg";
import profilePicture from "../../assets/images/profile.jpg";

const Header = () => {
    
  const { theme, toggleThemeMode } = useTheme();

  const showMobileMenu = () => {
    document.getElementById("main-wrapper").classList.toggle("show-sidebar");
  };

  const onToggleChange = () => toggleThemeMode();

  const isDark = theme.mode === DARK;

  return (
    <header className="topbar navbarbg" data-navbarbg="skin6">
      <nav className={`navbar navbar-${isDark ? "dark" : "light"} h-100`}>
        <div className="navbar-header" id="logobg" data-logobg="skin6">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <b className="logo-icon">
              <img src={logo} alt="homepage" className="dark-logo" />
            </b>
          </a>
          <button
            className="btn-link nav-toggler d-block d-md-none"
            onClick={() => showMobileMenu()}
          >
            <i className="ti-menu ti-close" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <Toggle onChange={onToggleChange} />
        <div className="collapse navbarbg show">
          <div className="dropdown">
            <img
              src={profilePicture}
              alt="user"
              className="rounded-circle"
              width="31"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

////////////////////////////////// toggle.jsx ///////////////////////////////////////

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Toggle = ({ checked, onChange, label = "" }) => {
    
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        onChange?.(event);
    };

    return (
        <div className="form-check form-switch">
            <input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                id="flexSwitchCheckDefault"
                checked={checked}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <label
                className="form-check-label"
                htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                {label}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
};

Toggle.propTypes = {
    checked: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    label: PropTypes.string,
};

export { Toggle };
```

Comment: You have to use `useTheme` in every component that you want to access the `theme`

Comment: I received every data in Header.jsx but I have to send some props . Toggle.jsx component and send (onChange, label, checked).
I have to solve this problem only by this way

Answer (score -1):

inside Toggle component, just use the states from the context
[image]

Comment: Please don't use images of code

Comment: Thank you guys but as you are looking I have to send props to Toggle component.
I'm a react learner and my tutors told me that I have to solve it only by this way

Comment: Just pass the isLight, setIsLight from the Header component to the Toggle component